# FFMPEG - How to save audio stream detached from video to file whithout transcoding

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I try to use fwrite() to save audio stream. But, generated file can not be opened.
At the same time, I also try to use av_frame_write() to write packet. But, it can not write.
Please help me with this problem. How to write audio stream without transcoding....

```
/* open the input file with generic avformat function */
err = avformat_open_input(input_format_context, filename, NULL, NULL);
if (err < 0) {
    return err;
}

/* If not enough info to get the stream parameters, we decode the
   first frames to get it. (used in mpeg case for example) */
ret = avformat_find_stream_info(*input_format_context, 0);
if (ret < 0) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "%s: could not find codec parameters\n", filename);
    return ret;
}

/* dump the file content */
av_dump_format(*input_format_context, 0, filename, 0);

for (size_t i = 0; i < (*input_format_context)->nb_streams; i++) {
    AVStream *st = (*input_format_context)->streams[i];
    if (st->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        FILE *file = NULL;
        file = fopen("C:\\Users\\MyPC\\Downloads\\test.aac", "wb");
        AVPacket reading_packet;
        av_init_packet(&reading_packet);
        while (av_read_frame(*input_format_context, &reading_packet) == 0) {
            if (reading_packet.stream_index == (int) i) {
            fwrite(reading_packet.data, 1, reading_packet.size, file);
            }
            av_free_packet(&reading_packet);   
        }
        fclose(file);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aac file require that frames have ADTS headers. If the file you are reading from does not use use ADTS frames (mp4 for example) you will need to manually create these headers, or use a bitstream filter. Also your code does not check to see if the codec is AAC.

Comment: Thank you so much Szatmary!
I've created new question here.
Please help me!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598792/ffmpeg-can-not-seek-audio-on-seeking-bar-of-audio-player

Comment: Hi Szatmary,
Please help me with this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714814/when-do-we-need-to-add-header-to-each-audio-frame