# FFMPEG - can not generate aac audio file by using av_write_frame()

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have video file (mp4). I want to detach audio stream (AAC format) from that file and save in PC. 
With below code, I use av_write_frame() to write packet. Then, generated file can not play. 
But, If I use fwrite() to write packet to file (like this [FFMPEG- Duration of audio file is inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598792/ffmpeg-can-not-seek-audio-on-seeking-bar-of-audio-player)). Then, generated file can play.

So, How to use av_write_frame() in the right way so that generated can play?

```
    int save_detached_audio(AVFormatContext **input_format_context,
                                AVStream **input_audio_stream,
                                AVCodecContext **input_codec_context,
                                const char *filename) {
int ret;
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder((*input_codec_context)->codec_id);
if (!codec) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to find codec of detached audio.\n");
    return -1;
}

AVFormatContext* output_format_context = NULL;
AVStream* output_stream = NULL;
ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&output_format_context, NULL, NULL, filename);
if (!output_format_context) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not allocate output format context.\n");
    return -1;
}


// open output file to write to it.
ret = avio_open2(&output_format_context->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, NULL);
if (ret < 0) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not open output file to write to it.\n");
    return -1;
}

AVOutputFormat* fmt = NULL;
fmt = av_guess_format(NULL, filename, NULL);
if (!fmt) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not find file format of detached audio.\n");
    return -1;
}

output_format_context->oformat = fmt;

// Create a new audio stream in the output file container. 
output_stream = avformat_new_stream(output_format_context, codec);
if (!output_stream) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not create a new stream in the output file container.\n");
    return -1;
}

output_stream->codec->bit_rate = (*input_codec_context)->bit_rate;
output_stream->codec->sample_rate = (*input_codec_context)->sample_rate;
output_stream->codec->channels = (*input_codec_context)->channels;


 ret = avformat_write_header(output_format_context, NULL);
 if (ret < 0) {
     av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not write header to output.\n");
     return -1;
 }

AVPacket reading_packet;
av_init_packet(&reading_packet);
while (av_read_frame(*input_format_context, &reading_packet) == 0) {
    if (reading_packet.stream_index == (*input_audio_stream)->index) {
        reading_packet.stream_index = 0;
        ret = av_write_frame(output_format_context, &reading_packet);
    }
    av_free_packet(&reading_packet);   
}
 ret = av_write_trailer(output_format_context);
 if (ret < 0) {
     av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not write trailer to output.\n");
     return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Because aac audio stream is written to file. So, we need to assign value of extradata and extradata_size for output_codec_context. These two values can be taken from input_codec_context