# When do we need to add header to each audio frame

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've done detaching audio (aac) from video (mp4). As I know, aac can play if and only each aac packet which is read from mp4 file is added ADTS header before writing to file.

I want to know when/ (which audio format) we need to add header ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the codec/container combination. AAC (as you know) Always requires a header. In the .aac container, there is a ADTS header every frame. In .mp4 there is a single header Audio Specific Config in the `mdhd` box. MP3 on the other hand always has a header per frame no matter the container. The number of codec container combinations is enormous and impractical to list in the stack overflow format.

Comment: Audio stream which is detached from video and then is written to file by using fwrite().
For AAC audio, definitely, there must be ADTS header per frame.
I try with MP3 audio which is detached from FLV video, we do not need to add any header to per frame. It still ensures that mp3 file can play.

Comment: correct. For FLV, aac has a Audio Specific Config in a sequence header tag, followed by raw aac frames. Mp3 does not have a sequence header in FLV. Every mp3 frame has a MPEG Audio Frame Header.